# mat-icon not showing

Tags: angular, angular-material, icons

So im working on a small company project and i am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-design-icons) npm package version 3.0.1 for the material-design-icons. I can display icons such as:

```
<mat-icon class="material-icons">info_outline</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-icons">info</mat-icon>
```

But i can't display:

```
<mat-icon class="material-icons">plagiarism_outline</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-icons">delete_forever_outline</mat-icon>
```

And i discovered that when i use:

```
<mat-icon class="material-icons">restore_from_trash</mat-icon>
```

It shows me this icon instead:

```
<mat-icon class="material-icons">restore</mat-icon>
```

Heres how it looks with a working icon VS not-working icon:

[image: Working example]
[image: Not-working example]

Any Ideas on how to make the icons appear or does anyone know as to why these icons aren't appearing?

Comment: Yes, it's an open issue: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/798, package is quite old. I use Angular Material and they are available (I've just tried plagiarism and delete_forever).

Comment: @CirrusMinor so are you using an npm package or how are you using those icons?

Comment: @Nelkin Yes, I'm using: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

Add this Link in index.html

```
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```